where exactly add the SEO on magento 2?
i see to many SEO on magento 2, on categories, on each products, etc... so where do i add the SEO? and if there is any good SEO generator that you can recommend. thanks.

Magento provides SEO features for specific categories and products, allowing you to add meta titles, keywords, and descriptions. By default, Magento uses the product name as the meta title, but you can customize this by creating a product CSV file and adding custom meta content for each product.
For advanced SEO management, you can use the SEO generator extension available at Adobe Market Place.
